# Express wild card route with parts split

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I've googled and checked other answers at SO but they are not what I'm looking for.

My wild card route:

```
app.all("/admin/*", function(request, response){

});
```

`request.params` provide

if uri is `/admin/login` = `{ '0': 'login' }`

if uri is `/admin/dashboard` = `{ '0': 'dashboard' }`

if uri is `/admin/dashboard/events` = `{ '0': 'dashboard/events' }`

But my expectation is.

```
{ '0': 'dashboard', '1': 'events' } //made up, not an actual result
```

Maybe my approach to tackle this is wrong, please suggest in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a capture group in a regular expression. That will reflect it in `request.params`. Then split the matching string to produce an array of results. For learning regex you can head to http://regexr.com/.

```html
app.all(/^\/admin\/(.*)/, function(req, resp) { 
    var params = req.params[0] && req.params[0].split('/'); 
});
```

Edit: Won't throw and error on no parameters.

Comment: No need in regexp in this case. You can use app.all("/admin/*") and req.params[0].split('/');

Comment: Thanks @user33946 for the answer and @Dyrk for the suggestion, I'd like to assign the `params` back to `request.params` object, for easier shuttling of `request` and `request.params` (new one) to different parts of the app, since `var params` is a local var in this case, any suggestions

Comment: Just pass it as an argument to your child. Assigning custom values to the response object is most probably not defined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add more route patterns:

```
app.all("/admin/*/*", function(req, res) {
    // Going to /admin/foo/bar gives you
    // { '0': 'foo', '1': 'bar' }
    console.log(req.params);

    res.end();
});
```

An even better idea might be to name your route parts, like this:

```
app.all("/admin/:one/:two", function(req, res) {
    // Going to /admin/foo/bar gives you
    // { one: 'foo', two: 'bar' }
    console.log(req.params);

    res.end();
});
```

Comment: I agree with your approach in another scenario, but let's say in my scenario I've a child module admin handling all admin related stuff (authentication and then routing again), the parent module handles public related stuff and doesn't want to know subparts of the admin module, if parent sees something /admin, it just forwards the request to child module, and child module has to figure out (there could be 5 or more parts), don't want parent module to know every bit and piece of it like :one/:two/:three/:four/:five etc.

Comment: That's a very different question from the one you posted :) You should post this as a separate question, but in short express 4 gives you some nice tools for creating modular sub-routes that will give you exactly what you want. Take a look at this: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router google about express sub-routes, and if you're still stumped I can definitely help you out.

Comment: you're right, I'm also getting clear about what I want... :) I'm interested to learn more about sub-router, there's a whole lot of param combinations for child module to handle that parent module doesn't need to bother about. Once delegated, the child module has to further refine uri's and params etc. or it's like another express router within express router. Please advise.

Comment: Ask your separate question please :)